# std::map crappy chars only in release mode

Tags: visual-studio-2008, mfc, dictionary, release, cstring

I have an std::map as parameter for an function and in Debug Mode (VS2008) the map have the correct keys and values, but when I start the program in Release there are crappy chars in to the map!

Code dump:

```
    std::map<CString, CString> libVersions;
    ... // fill values 
    utilFunctions->Function(&libVersions))

    bool UtilityFunctions::Function(std::map<CString,CString> *dllMapData)
    {
       ...
       map<CString,CString>::iterator it;

       for(it=dllMapData->begin(); it!=dllMapData->end(); it++)
       {  
          ...
       }
       ...
    }
```

Any ideas why this code is not functional in Release mode???

Thanks and greets

Comment: Can you post the code that fills the map? That's the interesting part :)

Comment: Switch to `std::string` instead of `CString` if possible, use references instead of pointers.

Comment: Does the string in the map look completely wrong or are there only a few extra characters?  Are the keys and values both wrong?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that in release you are still compiling against the debug CRT and don't have _DEBUG defined (or vice versa).

Comment: Hi! Runtime Library is set to /MT and Generate Debug Info is No! In Debug Mode /MTd and /DEBUG! In the map all chars are crappy (not only single characters differs)! Any other ideas! greets leon22

Comment: @leon22:  What defines have you got set in release? (Its under C/C++->Preprocessor)

Comment: WIN32;NDEBUG;_WINDOWS;_VC80_UPGRADE=0x0600;_MBCS;$(NOINHERIT) in Release and WIN32;_DEBUG;_WINDOWS in Debug! greets leon22

Comment: @leon22:  Hmmm ... that ruins that idea then :(